# Python find indexwise maximum average minimum for list of 100 sublists

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing 100+ sublists. Need to get index wise maximum for this scenario using python.

```
L1= [3,2,7]
L2= [1,5,7]
L3= [10,3,6]
```

1. Get max value from index 0 of all lists
2. Get min value from index 1 of all lists
3. Get avg value from index 2 of all lists

Result list is `[10,2,6.666]`

I don't have further code, there are at least 100 such lists for which this calculation is required

Comment: `[f(v) for f, v in zip((max, min, mean), zip(L1, L2, L3))]`. Imports: [`mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean).

Comment: Don't repost closed questions. Fix the reason they were closed and submit for reopening https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75032560/python-find-indexwise-maximum-for-a-list-containing-n-sublists

Comment: Also what you've described isn't an "indexwise maximum". Please [edit] your question so the title summarizes what you're actually asking

Answer (score 0):

I can share with you one approach

let us say there are only 2 lists ..  you should try to extend this logic to 100 lists

```
L1: [2,8, 1]
L2: [3, 1, 6]

so the answer will be

[3,8,6]
```

to solve this make a list which will store the answer

```
ans = [0,0,0]
```

now iterate over every list and just replace every index with the largest value you see at that index

after first list ans will look like

```
[2,8,1]
```

coz all values are greater than zero

when you iterate over 2nd list , 3 is greater than 2 and 6 is greater than 1 so you just update them

and your answer will become

```
[3,8,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple: https://numpy.org/

Transform your list of lists "LoL" into an array...

```py
import numpy as np
LoL = np.asarray([L1, L2, L3])
```

...and then apply those aggregations...

Check the docs for details. E.g., "max": https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html#numpy.ndarray.max

Answer (score 0):

using zip():

**Code:**

```
L1= [3,2,7]
L2= [1,5,7]
L3= [10,3,6]
counter=0
res=[]
for lis in zip(L1,L2,L3):  #It brings same index element together in the form of tuples  [i.e (3, 1, 10),(2, 5, 3),(7, 7, 6)]
    if counter==0:
        res.append(max(lis))
        counter+=1
    elif counter==1:
        res.append(min(lis))
        counter+=1
    else:
        res.append(sum(lis)/len(lis)) #mean=sum_of_all_element/total_number_of_element
print(res) #Output [10, 2, 6.666666666666667]
```